# Bootstrap css overrides custom css style

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have MVC 5 project which generated built in bootstrap.css and Site.css files. I'm trying to add custom color navbar which I generated on [TWBSColor](https://work.smarchal.com/twbscolor/index.php). I pasted generated code in Site.css file which is located in Content folder. I even named it .navbar-custom instead of usual .navbar or .navbar-inverse, just to make sure it's different.

In my _Layout.cshtml I have

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

and I wrapped necessary content in

```
<div class="navbar-custom navbar-brand navbar-fixed-bottom">
```

but it still either shows white one or black one if I use inverse. How to get my custom navbar to work?

Comment: Have you inspected the output in your browser? Its likely you have a conflicting style and you may need to mark one as more _important_ than the other...

Comment: I'm not sure how to check that, since when I inspect the top div's class is `navbar-custom` and there is no such name in bootstrap.css file, but it still doesn't show the color I picked.

Comment: Make sure that your site.css file is listed after the bootstrap css. If there are any conflicts, it will take the last entry

Comment: I know, since I did that when I wrote stuff in the plain html, but now in `_Layout.cshtml`, I don't have just thing, but instead only `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")`. I guess it calls whole Content folder, so I have no idea how to check which .css file is called first.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Use this link [**to learn how to inspect elemetn for CSS**](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/). My guess is your custom CSS has a lower specificity than those in the CSS of Bootstrap so the lose out (don't get applied).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're loading bootstrap into a project you must load your custom CSS stylesheet's after bootstrap. An example is below

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Custom CSS File -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fileName.css" />
```

If this does not solve the issue, the please view this tutorial on CSS Specificity

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fy07HYm-geM&index=6&list=PLqGj3iMvMa4IOmy04kDxh_hqODMqoeeCy

Comment: I know, but the problem is that I have ASP.NET project which calls all css files with its `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")` in .cshtml file, so I can't set which one to be called first.

Comment: Is there a way to ignore what files get loaded by ASP.net? Say if you ignored your custom stylesheet and then manually load it in your template view? (I'm assuming ASP.Net is a framework? I'm not familiar)